# How to convert the spectrum type ("Spectrum" -> "Convert Data to")

Tags: dm-script

Is there a manner in which one can convert the spectrum type, for instance to EELS, by DM scripting? This screenshot represents what I'm referring to. I'd like to import a dataset using the GMS 3.4 Python interface, and then turn that into a EELS dataset for further processing (ideally without having to manually interface with the screenshotted menu bar).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.
The "type" is simply a meta-data tag
[image: Tags]
which you can easily set with the TagGroup commands.

There is, however, one complication: 
Data "registers" itself with DM when it first appears. Changing the meta-tags manually doesn't change this registration. (The menu command, however, does.)
Thus, you will only see effect of the type change when
either:

- You save, close and reopen the data
- You clone the data, throw away the original, and display the clone

The second option might cause issues with data-linkage though, as the unique image ID of the data is newly created.

---

Example using the first method (requires save & load):

```
image img:=GetFrontImage()
TagGroup tg = img.ImageGetTagGroup()
tg.TagGroupSetTagAsString("Meta Data:Signal","EELS")
imageDocument doc = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()
doc.ImageDocumentSave(0)
string path = doc.ImageDocumentGetCurrentFile()
doc.ImageDocumentClose(0)
doc = NewImageDocumentFromFile(path)
doc.ImageDocumentShow()
```

Comment: Also note: If you load data by script and perform the tag-changes prior first display, it will also work. It is the first displaying of data that triggers registration.

Comment: Excellent! I was able to do this in the python interface as well. Adding the tag before ShowImage works great!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option is to rely on the menu command. If it is present, then you can simply use the `ChoseMenuItem()` command to invoke it. 
However, the command will only be available with the UI when the data you want to change is front-most (i.e. not a script window!) You will need to ensure by script, that this is the case. A simple `ShowWindow()` will do.

```
image img:=GetFrontImage()
img.ShowImage()
if ( !ChooseMenuItem("Spectrum","Convert Data To","None") )
    Throw( "Conversion to none failed.")
if ( !ChooseMenuItem("Spectrum","Convert Data To","EDS") )
    Throw( "Conversion to none failed.")
```

Disadvantage of this solution: You will get the user-prompts.